# how to access add ons for shadow of the colossus

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

I've downloaded/installed the Wanders Pack add on for Shadow of the Colossus but cannot find the in game items - the bow, cape and the black/white finish for Agro.
How do I activate/access these items? There is nothing on any of the game menus that mentions downloaded content.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ShadowoftheColossus/comments/7vzbho/wanders_pack_not_showing_in_game/dtwa5ky/) article, you can access the Wander Packs items by opening up your map and then pressing triangle.

This can be seen done in the first few seconds on Youtube